# Converting Stock Returns to Time Series object in R

Tags: r, data-structures, time-series, stock

I'm having some trouble with converting daily stock returns into a time series.

My data is just a data.frame object.

```
data$Returns

> .0317
> -.0126
> -.0279
```

Then, when I try to convert the data.frame to a time series object, these returns seem to arbitrarily change.

```
data.ts <- ts(data, freq=365)

> 55  17   30
```

Why is the ts function changing the data?

Comment: You probably meant to convert `data$returns` to a `ts` object, not the entire data frame. Try `ts(data$returns, freq=365)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example that will accomplish what you're after:

```
data = data.frame(
    Date = c("2004-01-01", "2004-01-02", "2004-01-03"), 
    Returns = c(.0317, -.0126, -.0279))

data.ts = ts(data$Returns, freq = 365)
data.ts

> data.ts
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(1, 3) 
Frequency = 365 
[1]  0.0317 -0.0126 -0.0279
```